# code does not compile in g++ while it does in clang++

Tags: c++, c++11, g++, clang++

So I have this really short code:

**test.cpp**

```
class Base {
    public:
        Base(int i) {};
};

class Child : public virtual Base {
    using Base::Base;
};

int main(int argc, char * argv[]) {
    auto *child = new Child(1);
    return 0;
};
```

It compiles well under clang++ (3.8.0):

```
$ clang++ test.cpp -std=c++11
```

while it fails under g++ (5.4.0):

```
$ g++ test.cpp -std=c++11
test.cpp: In function ‘int main(int, char**)’:
test.cpp:14:30: error: use of deleted function ‘Child::Child(int)’
     auto *child = new Child(1);
                              ^
test.cpp:8:17: note: ‘Child::Child(int)’ is implicitly deleted because the default definition would be ill-formed:
     using Base::Base;
                 ^
test.cpp:8:17: error: no matching function for call to ‘Base::Base()’
test.cpp:3:9: note: candidate: Base::Base(int)
         Base(int i) {};
         ^
test.cpp:3:9: note:   candidate expects 1 argument, 0 provided
test.cpp:1:7: note: candidate: constexpr Base::Base(const Base&)
 class Base {
       ^
test.cpp:1:7: note:   candidate expects 1 argument, 0 provided
test.cpp:1:7: note: candidate: constexpr Base::Base(Base&&)
test.cpp:1:7: note:   candidate expects 1 argument, 0 provided
```

For some reason g++ expects `Base` class to have the default constructor. Why is that?

**EDIT:** This also fails for copying. This code:

```
auto child = Child(1);
```

produces the same error under g++, while this:

```
Child child(1);
```

works fine. But I still don't understand why?

**EDIT 2:** Without `virtual` keyword it works fine under both compilers.

Comment: Interesting.  This compiles if you remove the `virtual` inheritance for Child, or if you explicitly define a constructor for Child: `Child(int i) : Base(i) {}`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think it is a g++ bug.

From [N2540](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2008/n2540.htm), emphasis by me:

> Typically, inheriting constructor definitions for classes with virtual bases will be ill-formed, **unless** the virtual base supports default initialization, or **the virtual base is a direct base, and named as the base forwarded-to.** Likewise, all data members and other direct bases must support default initialization, or any attempt to use a inheriting constructor will be ill-formed. Note: ill-formed when used, not declared.

As far as I can tell, your example exactly fulfils the condition I've emphasized, so I think it should work. However note that this is a working draft change proposal; it might have changed before incorporating into the final standard. But I'd expect that if anything changed, it's likely allowing more cases, not forbidding more cases.

Maybe someone with access to the actual standard can double check.